My block plugin break causes "an unexpected error in the block editor"
I created a block with the wp-create-block, but somehow it causes errors.
The block and the code is available on Github
It can transform to and from a Group block, but when I create group and try open the transform control (ie the popup-control in the block editor which allows transformation), the editor closes and I get the message "An unexpected error occured with the block editor" (in Norwegian, approx translation here). Next to the message are the buttons "Copy post text" and "Error with post copy".
In the console, the following error is reported (I removed the actual domain from the message):
Error: Block type 'create-block/factbox' is not registered.
$e https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=6612d078dfaf28b875b8:12
mr https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=6612d078dfaf28b875b8:19
transform https://[myurl]/wp-content/plugins/factbox/build/index.js?ver=9ee00f2961a71ab6508a:1
Ar https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/blocks.min.js?ver=6612d078dfaf28b875b8:19
PS https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/block-editor.min.js?ver=868d782fcb169133c92b:26
wt https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
vr https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
js https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
wl https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
bl https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
yl https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
il https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
ol https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
v https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
ce https://[myurl]/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10

Otherwise, the plugin works as expected.
Any ideas to what is wrong with my code that causes this?

whats the error message? If it's not offering you an error message it will be in the browser console. Remember that a question must be self contained, you can link elsewhere for supporting material but it needs to be understood and answerable without going offsite, you'll need to put the relevant code inside your question instead of linking to github

I see stuff like inline click handlers using onclick etc, these are a no go and not something that should be done in React, expect this to break. I also see usage of experimental APIs, without seeing the error message though these are all guesses. As an aside the readme claims group blocks can't be left/right aligned in newer WP versions which isn't true, it's the justification control in the sidebar

thanks for your feedback @TomJNowell I'll add the console-message in post.
The experimental APIs are also in use in regular Wordpress, so I thought they were quite safe to use.
I wasn't aware that simple inline javascript could cause issues with React. Is this documented anywhere on wordpress.org or similar?

The error message is telling you the problem:

Error: Block type 'create-block/factbox' is not registered.

Your renamed the block so it wouldn't contain create-block in its name, but forgot to do a search replace of all files, leaving a create-block/factbox reference in a transform function
